# What is the difference between sequential access and sequential traversal of elements in data structures

Tags: data-structures

Sequential traversal is the main difference between linear and non linear data structures.Can anyone explain it briefly?

Comment: Could you make your question a bit more detailed?  Are you asking for the difference in sequential traversal between these two data structures, or the difference between these two data structures?

Comment: I am looking for the difference in sequential traversal between these two data structures only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear data structure is something like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

For instance, lists and arrays.  Each element is followed by a single element.  Traversal is trivial, as you simply go from one element to the next.  For instance, if you start at A, you only have one next element B, from B you only have one next element C and so on.

A non-linear data structure is something like this:

```
   A
 /   \
 B    C
/ \  / \
D E  F G
```

For instance, a tree.  Notice how A is followed by two elements; B and C, and each of them is followed by two elements.  Now traversal is more complex, because once you start from A, you have a choice of going to either B and C.  What's more, once at B, you have a choice of going further down, or going "sideways" to C. In this case (a tree), your traversal options are breadth-first or depth-first.